# UI-Bootstrap date picker, icon and label not aligning properly

Tags: css, html, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using the Angular ui-bootstrap directives and having some trouble getting the alignment right when I try to add a label. It seems no matter where I place the label in the HTML (like above or below the input group wrappers) the label and the icon are lined up, but not the text box. I've tried looking it up here, but the suggestions (which are for the most part applied) never seem to have any impact. I'm probably missing some small detail in the styling, but I would appreciate any help given. I was able to replicate the issue with snippets of my code and here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IeJRsldAXVsI9JewoC7j?p=preview) to look at. If you think more would be helpful, please let me know.

Here is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html ng-app="AppCtrl">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.js"></script>
        <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
        <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.3.3.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="script.js"></script>
       </head>
       <body>
         <div ng-controller="DatePickerCtrl">
           <div class="row">
              <div class="">
                 <p class="input-group">
                    <label class="control-label form-inline" for="bookingDate">Booking Date:</label>
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default calButton" ng-click="open1()">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                      </button>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" name="bookingDate" class="form-control datePicker" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                 </p>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

And my css (my javascript if that matters is in the plunker):

```
/*----------Date Picker---------*/
   .full button span {
       background-color: limegreen;
       border-radius: 32px;
       color: black;
    }

    .partially button span {
       background-color: orange;
       border-radius: 32px;
       color: black;
    }

    .label {
    float: left;
    text-align: right; 
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  }

  #reservationInfo input[type=text] {
  float: left;
  width: 120px; 
}
```

Thanks in advance! :)

## Update:

After some hours of fiddling around with the markup I've made some progress. I simplified the markup and removed the spans wrapping the buttons. I got everything to line up properly, but for some reason the textbox is appearing before everything, and I can't seem to fix this now. Anyone know what might be happening? Below is my updated markup and I've updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IeJRsldAXVsI9JewoC7j?p=preview) as well.

```
<body id="reservationInfo">
  <div ng-controller="DatePickerCtrl">
    <label class="control-label" for="bookingDate">Booking Date:</label>

    <button type="button" name="bookingDate" class="btn btn-default calButton" ng-click="open1()">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
    <input type="text" class="form-control datePicker" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I just used the below properties and it seems to do the trick. A little too much time wasted on figuring this out, but that's life I guess.

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

I updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IeJRsldAXVsI9JewoC7j?p=preview) as well. Below is my updated css.

```
/*----------Date Picker---------*/

.full button span {
  background-color: limegreen;
  border-radius: 32px;
  color: black;
}

.partially button span {
  background-color: orange;
  border-radius: 32px;
  color: black;
}

#reservationInfo input[type=text] {
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  border-left: none;
  margin: -10px;
}

.calIcon {
  width: 20px;
  border-right: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If someone has a better solution though, I'm more than willing to see it!

Comment: I'm on the latest Firefox and the elements don't align in your Plunkr :(